# Is there a word for an individual spark in a firework?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

For example, what would the single spark in the red 'circle' be called?[image]

Comment: Isn't that a *spark* after all?

Comment: "Jupiter is a single spark seen with the naked eye—a single instance of an object. Seen through a good telescope, you will see Jupiter resolved into many sparks. Each new spark is a satellite of Jupiter— ...." https://books.google.com/books?isbn=1599049236

Comment: Hand-drawn circles! *upvote...*

Comment: This question is unclear. First, how technical of an answer do you want?  Second, what exactly are you asking about? The 'spark' (exploding pellet) is a *star* that is traveling through the air leaving behind a *comet*. The comet can be called a tail, trail,  or streak. Again, how technical do you want to be and exactly what part are you asking about?

Comment: Maybe 'sparxel' ?

Comment: I'm flagging this question for closure due to lacking the requisite contextual sentence for [tag:single-word-requests], which seems to be necessary in this case to disambiguate between which of these answers is the most accurate.

Comment: Regrettably, one of my favorite words — _scintilla_ — narrowly misses the mark. Its Latin root literally meant "spark", and though it retains this connection in the word _scintillation_ (which in physics is the literal process of emitting flashes of light) and even the adjective _scintillating_ (fascinating), in English usage the word _scintilla_ is no more than figuratively related to combustion or radiance. You might say "I haven't a scintilla of interest" to mean "I haven't even a tiny (figurative) spark of interest", but it doesn't literally mean a "spark" as in a firework. :sad face:

Answer (score 52):

The correct technical name for a single spark of a firework is a "star". Each star is a small roughly spherical pellet made mainly of gunpowder.

A fuse ignites a lifting charge and a time-delay fuse. Whilst the lifting charge burns, it propels the firework into the air, then near to the peak of its trajectory the time-delay fuse ignites a bursting charge packed behind the stars. This bursting charge both ignites and distributes the stars. Chemical additives in the stars determine their burn colour. They are called stars both before and after ignition.

You can find many labelled diagrams of the inner workings of fireworks if you search online for "anatomy of a firework" or similar. Here is one example:

[image: This is a diagram, shows a dissection of two fireworks: One of the fireworks is cylindrical and referred to as 'Italian-style', and a mostly cylindrical shell, with an almost conical shape with the point cut off of it protruding from the bottom, referred to as 'Oriental-style'. The image lists the various parts, including the quick match fuse, the time delay fuse, the bursting charge, the lifting charge, the paper case and most importantly the stars. The stars appear to be spheres made out of compacted gunpowder granules, above the lifting charge, around the bursting charge, and inside the shell. The image has text indicating it is sourced from discovery.com and copyrighted by KRT, circa 2002.]

Comment: True,  but it's not clear that the OP is asking about the *star* and/or the trail /tail/streak/comet behind it; which is why I asked for clarification rather than guess 
 what the OP is asking about.

Comment: Indeed, it would be good if the OP were to clarify the question. My assumption that he was referring primarily to the star (rather than the tail) was based on his referring to it as a "spark", ie an individual point of light (rather than a "streak" or similar).

Comment: -1 Wonder how you could complete miss the point. "Star" is **not** the spark of light -- please re-read your source. Sorry to disappoint. Also, check dictionaries for *star* and let me know if any source defines it this way.

Comment: @Kris the image he uses, uses 'stars' in step 4 and 5 (the source). And this may be more of firework jargon than a general definition (like comet in my answer, which doesn't have a firework definition that I could see but doesn't stop pyros from using it)

Comment: @Kris - "7.I.7 Pyrotechny. A small piece of combustible composition, used in rockets, mines, etc., which as seen burning high in the air resembles a star." source: OED CD-ROM v4.0

Answer (score 11):

You may call them ***streaks***.

Usage examples:
[Google search for "firework streak"](https://www.google.com/search?q=firework+streak)

MW:

> **[streak](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/streak)**
>   *noun*
>
> **3 a** :  a narrow band of light

Collins:

> **[streak](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/streak)** [in American]
>   *noun*
>   **2.  a** ray of light or a flash, as of lightning
>
> Webster’s New World College Dictionary, 4th Edition. Copyright © 2010
>   by Houghton Mifflin Harcourt. All rights reserved.

Answer (score 9):

**[Trail](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/trail)**

> to grow to such length as to droop over toward the ground
>
> to move, flow, or extend slowly in thin streams

**[Tail](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tail)**

> something that in shape, appearance, or position is like an animal's tail

Example (as more than the head is circled):

> Palm Tree –
> An aerial effect that produces a gold or silver stem as the shell rises into the sky (known as a rising tail), followed by a brocade or willow effect that creates palm fronds. It resembles a gold or silver palm tree in the sky.<sup>1</sup>

**[Flare](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/flare)**

> a fire or blaze of light used especially to signal, illuminate, or attract attention

**Comet**

from [American Pyro technic terms](http://www.americanpyro.com/glossary-of-pyrotechnic-terms)

> A pellet of composition which is propelled from a mortar or shell and produces a long tailed effect

<sub>1 [Usage examples](http://keystonefireworks.com/news/types-of-fireworks-effects/)</sub>

Comment: Nitpicking here, but I don't think 'tail' really fits. Also, a 'flare' is predominantly a thing on its own (as in rescue flare), and 'Comets' are extraterrestrial (as your definition shows) and 'pellets' are when they aren't alight (plus it's jargon)...

Comment: @marcellothearcane I included tail because it was mentioned on 'Usage examples'  in multiple types of fireworks

Comment: @depperm: just because it _has_ a tail does not mean that it _is_ a tail. E.g. cats, dogs, even snakes :) (if you're wondering about the snakes, their tail only starts at their anus, similar to all animals. The rest of their body is not a tail)

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the provided answers, I would refer to it as an **offshoot**.

> [**Offshoot**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/offshoot)
>
> 1. A side shoot or branch on a plant.
>
> 1.1. A thing that develops from something else.
> *‘commercial offshoots of universities’*

In this case, I consider it related to 1.1 (more literal than its example showcases), because it is a fragment of the initial explosion.

Answer (score -5):

It's just a spark. Sparks are already individual. Your question is invalid. When you create a fire, you create it using sparks. When you are successful at creating one streak of light, you call it a spark. Therefore it is a spark for that one streak of light.

Comment: I think your answer is invalid. Just because such a "streak of light" can be called a _spark_ doesn't mean English doesn't have a better word than _spark_. Therefore, it's a valid question, even if no better answer than _spark_ exists.